# TensorflowJS: TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetch' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I have an angular 7 application and I'm trying to load the mobilenet model by following [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/mobilenet) example.

I installed the tensorflowjs by running `npm install @tensorflow/tfjs` (following [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/setup) instructions) and the mobilenet model by running `@tensorflow-models/mobilenet`.

After that I imported the mobile net by doing:

```
import * as mobilenet from '@tensorflow-models/mobilenet';
```

And execute the following code in order to load the model:

```
mobilenet.load().then(() => {
     obs.next();
}).catch((err) => {
     console.log(err);
     console.log("ERROR");
});
```

But I'm receiving the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetch' of undefined
    at new e (tf-core.esm.js:17)
    at browserHTTPRequest (tf-core.esm.js:17)
    at httpRequestRouter (tf-core.esm.js:17)
    at tf-core.esm.js:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function.e.getHandlers (tf-core.esm.js:17)
    at Function.e.getLoadHandlers (tf-core.esm.js:17)
    at Object.getLoadHandlers (tf-core.esm.js:17)
    at e.findIOHandler (tf-converter.esm.js:17)
    at e.<anonymous> (tf-converter.esm.js:17)
```

Does anyone know what is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the problem was that I had different versions for @tensorflow/tfs and @tensorflow/tfjs-core on my packade.json.

So, I change my package config from:

```
...
"@tensorflow/tfjs": "^1.1.2",
"@tensorflow/tfjs-core": "^1.0.2",
...
```

To:

```
...
"@tensorflow/tfjs": "^1.1.2",
"@tensorflow/tfjs-core": "^1.1.2",
...
```

And the error vanished.